# What is this anime about a guy with white hair and an infected(?) eye, who often cracks his index finger?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Okay, so my friend who I had a falling out with used to watch this anime on her laptop. I'd like to watch it but I don't know the title of the series and I can't ask her for obvious reasons. Here are what I remember:

- It's not too old... 2013-2015, maybe
- Main character is a guy with white hair and an infected (?) eye, but his eye can actually become a normal eye. He is a cannibal, if I remember correctly
- He, along with many other characters, have four red tails coming out of his back, some others have wings. Everyone with tails or wings are cannibals, if I'm not mistaken. All of the cannibals have infected eyes which they can 'turn off' and are stronger than other humans
- The art style is pretty good, as in not everyone has oversized eyes
- Not too sure about the genre. It's something between horror and science fiction
- Hair and eye colors aren't too realistic
- I actually remember a scene where he was a fighting a big blonde man in a white suit who is trying to eat him or something like that. He ended up forcing the man to count and then eating him instead
- I just remembered, the main character often cracked his index finger. He did this over and over again

I'm sorry if this is too vague, please bear in mind that I only saw two or three episodes in passing. I'd really like to know the name of this anime.

Comment: I think that if they do remove all identification requests except for a few, this should be one of the few. There is no way physically possible that it is not Tokyo Ghoul, which is proof its a good question.

Answer (score 6):

You should make up with your friend (friendship should triumph over quarrels). Then you can enjoy the rest of [*Tokyo Ghoul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul) together again.

[image: crack goes the finger]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhbS4-W-hpg

Comment: yeah its tokyo ghoul awesome anime, with an anti hero